# Core file Issue

Tags: coredump, dbx

Any idea about the core file debugged by dbx debugger. I am not getting why this core file is generated. Please help me on this

```
For information about new features see `help changes'
To remove this message, put `dbxenv suppress_startup_message 7.6' in your .dbxrc
Reading mhost.new
core file header read successfully
Reading ld.so.1
Reading librt.so.1
Reading libclntsh.so.9.0
Reading libm.so.2
Reading libnsl.so.1
Reading libsocket.so.1
Reading libgen.so.1
Reading libdl.so.1
Reading libthread.so.1
Reading libc.so.1
Reading libaio.so.1
Reading libmd.so.1
Reading libwtc9.so
Reading libsched.so.1
Reading libc_psr.so.1
WARNING!!
A loadobject was found with an unexpected checksum value.
See `help core mismatch' for details, and run `proc -map'
to see what checksum values were expected and found.
dbx: warning: Some symbolic information might be incorrect.
t@1 (l@1) program terminated by signal SEGV (no mapping at the fault address)
0xff3be704: elf_find_sym+0x0114:        ldsb     [%l0 + %l4], %o2
(dbx) where
current thread: t@1
=>[1] elf_find_sym(0xffbfbbd8, 0xffbfbc68, 0xffbfbc64, 0xf194, 0xfe5986d2, 0xff3f0358), at 0xff3be704
  [2] _lookup_sym(0xff3f7360, 0xffbfbbd8, 0xffbfbc68, 0xffbfbc64, 0x0, 0xff3f0358), at 0xff3bbb7c
  [3] lookup_sym(0xffbfbc6c, 0xffbfbc68, 0xffbfbc64, 0xff3f7360, 0x1, 0xfe5986d2), at 0xff3bbe6c
  [4] elf_bndr(0x84d, 0xff391d38, 0xfe5c2124, 0xfe5986d2, 0xff3f42f0, 0x0), at 0xff3d207c
  [5] elf_rtbndr(0xfe5c2124, 0xfe6c3800, 0x1c00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xff3b84fc
  [6] 0xfe6bf3c4(0x0, 0x1cc4, 0xfe6c3800, 0xfe6c5180, 0xff352a00, 0x1c00), at 0xfe6bf3c4
  [7] _exithandle(0xfe6c5400, 0xfe6c3800, 0x1c00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfe5c2124
  [8] exit(0x0, 0xffbfbe4c, 0xffbfbeb4, 0x139800, 0xff350100, 0x0), at 0xfe5b0550
```

Answer (score 0):

`SEGV` indicates an access to undefined memory.  It occurred in elf_find_sym.  If debug symbols were included, then the dump would indicate the line number.

Use `gcc -g`  <files>... to include debug symbol and line number information.

Comment: Actually this core file was created by an online application on 09 Feb. Do we any option in dbx to include debug symbols

Comment: dbx would use symbols if they were present.  If you're not building the application, then Google for this error associated with the product.  Probably someone else has had trouble too.

Answer (score 0):

A proper stack would help in finding out what might have caused the crash. Assuming this core is generated on Solaris platform and you are analyzing a core generated on a different system.

In that case it would be good to collect all the dependent libraries from the environment where the core is generated. Extract them locally, and map the local directories using the pathmap subcommand in dbx.

for example, if a library is present in the failing environment under /home/app/lib and on the local environment where core is analyzed is under /home/user/app/lib
(dbx) pathmap /home/app/lib /home/user/app/lib

If there are multiple such paths, then all the directories need to be mapped to the respective local directories. Once all the paths are mapped, you can run the following

```
(dbx) debug executable-name corefile-name
```

Alternatively you can also try

- mdb debugger
- pstack command on the core file.